# Is it possible to calculate region based on specified coordinate and screen size

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native, latitude-longitude, react-native-maps

I have a coordinate and I want to set map region for it.
Problem is that when I pass coordinate to create a region for it to a function that coordinate is in the center of region.
I don't want it to be in center I need it up a bit.
If for example map is 500 in height I want to set region so that coordinate is in the center of top 250.

```
function getRegionForCoordinates(points) {
  // points should be an array of { latitude: X, longitude: Y }
  let minX, maxX, minY, maxY;

  // init first point
  ((point) => {
    minX = point.latitude;
    maxX = point.latitude;
    minY = point.longitude;
    maxY = point.longitude;
  })(points[0]);

  // calculate rect
  points.map((point) => {
    minX = Math.min(minX, point.latitude);
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, point.latitude);
    minY = Math.min(minY, point.longitude);
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, point.longitude);
  });

  const midX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
  const midY = (minY + maxY) / 2;
  let deltaX = (maxX - minX);
  let deltaY = (maxY - minY);

  return {
    latitude: midX,
    longitude: midY,
    latitudeDelta: 0.002,
    longitudeDelta: 0.002
  };
}
```

Is this possible to calculate?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this problem but it's done with MapKit (Apple Maps), so not sure if that really helps you but it might give you some idea maybe...

MapKit has this `MKCoordinateRegion` type:

```
var region: MKCoordinateRegion {
    let regionSize = 10000.0
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionSize, regionSize)
    return region
}
```

and it's possible to zoom map to region with that:

```
map.setRegion(region, animated: animated)
```

I also had some view at the bottom and wanted to center annotation in the upper part of the screen so I had to do some calculation before setting map region:

```
let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottomViewHeight / 2)
let screenHeight = UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait ? view.bounds.height : view.bounds.width
let offsetScreenPercentage = Double(offset.y / screenHeight)
region.center.latitude -= region.span.latitudeDelta * offsetScreenPercentage * 2
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

`longitudeDelta` and `latitudeDelta` are differences between two sides of the map and top and bottom. These values can be used to calculate different positions in map in a given region. To learn more about these values you can read this article ([*MKMapView and Zoom Levels: A Visual Guide*](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/))

With this information all you need to do is a small calculation. First you set your marker coordinate to the coordinate you have, then you can add or subtract some portion of the `latitudeDelta` from your delta and set the region to that position.

Below is the sample code to describe it better;

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    region: null,
    marker: null,
  };
  setMarkerAndRegion = () => {
    const initialReagion = {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    };

    // Set marker to the region's LatLong
    const marker = {
      latitude: initialReagion.latitude,
      longitude: initialReagion.longitude,
    };

    // Subtract the required amount from the latitude
    const region = {
      latitude: initialReagion.latitude - initialReagion.latitudeDelta / 4,
      longitude: initialReagion.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: initialReagion.latitudeDelta,
      longitudeDelta: initialReagion.longitudeDelta,
    };

    this.setState({ region, marker });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setMarkerAndRegion();
  }
  render() {
    const { region, marker } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {region && (
          <MapView style={{ flex: 1 }} initialRegion={region}>
            {marker && <Marker coordinate={marker} />}
          </MapView>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```